# Adjective 'young' after a noun here

Tags: adjectives

This is from an article in the CBC news:[What parents need to know about Facebook's new messenger app for kids](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/facebook-messenger-kids-pringle-1.4433273)

> "That's why Facebook is doing this, of course — it's a safe way to get
>   their brand into the family **young**."

Is using 'young' after a noun 'family' in this sentence a right usage? I've googled but without an answer. Can you, for example, say 'the family rich', 'the family poor', 'the family old'....etc.?

Comment: **young** is a noun there and **family** is the adjective. **Young** is a synonym for **offspring**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20young%20of%20the%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo: Oh!, never occurred 'young' is a noun here. I've heard 'a family law' 'a family show' 'a family name' 'a family tradition' ' a family friend' ...etc. But never heard 'a family young'. Is it used commonly?

Comment: *The* family young.  It is a collective noun formed from the adjective. It is very common, especially in naturalist contexts. See the link I added to the comment above.  The quick and the dead, the young and the old, the healthy and the infirm.

Comment: I read it as an adjective, as a sort of small clause "into the family young" = "into the family while it is/they are young"..

Comment: @Colin Fine.  A viable reading, but I'd expect **early** if that was the intended meaning.

Comment: @Colin Fine: The above sentence means that Facebook company is trying to introduce their brand early into younger generation (less than 13 yr.) in order to make kids keep using Facebook when they become old enough to use Facebook without a parent's consent.

Comment: @ColinFine You are absolutely right. That's exactly what it means and it is indeed an adjective here. "**a state**"

Comment: @SovereignSun: Colin may be right, and that might be what the person quoted intended, but the statement is not at all clear. The verb phrase ***get their brand into* the family** certainly has more grace than ***get their brand into* the young**. But people writing about marketing efforts and brand positioning often use graceless expressions when referring to the targets of those efforts.   If "family" is the object of **into**, does **young** refer to a young family (while the family is young)?  Are families with tweens young families?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm still waiting for a reply from Richard if he does respond cause if he doesn't I'll be dissappointed.

Comment: @SovereignSun: whether he intended one meaning or the other is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, I don't like my answer being downvoted, so it is quite relevant to me.

Comment: @SovereignSun: Your suggestion that **young** refers to the immature brand is also a viable parsing (setting aside the issue of whether Facebook is to be considered young at this stage).  But the context suggests that the young referred to are the target audience.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, thank you, but I intended to say that the product of their brand is joining at an early stage. I can't believe that such an educated person as Richard would incorrectly use the adjective or make such a confusion in such a simple quote.

Comment: @SovereignSun: edumacation don't make you perfect.   I don't understand your intransitive use of "is joining".

Comment: Guys, I received the e-mail. You can now see the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can say is that I can't see anything intrinsically wrong with it, but it sounds terribly weird to me. I get what they're trying to say, but it conjures images of branding herds of cattle. And "young" is more often used with biological species than with a modifier like family. "Youth" might be slightly more appropriate, but I'm still picturing burning flesh.

In other words, I think "family young" sounds odd, but I also think "get their brand into" is odd. I'd probably say something more along the lines of "saturate the youth market with their brand."

**Edit:** From the comments, it's become clear to me that I didn't actually understand what they were trying to say here. But for whitecap, you can indeed say things like "the family rich" when you mean "the rich people of the family" and so on. But "rich" is used by itself as a collective noun, too. "There are too many tax loopholes for the rich."

The young is similarly used as a collective noun. "Mammals breastfeed their young." Whether or not it was intended to be a noun in this quotation is up for debate.

Comment: **Young** isn't a noun here. "**young**" modifies the word "**brand**".

Comment: I see your reading, now. I still think it's bad writing.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Consider this, "**The kids that were rescued from the cave had gone there unwarned**"

Comment: I don't think it's equivalent. There's no way to misinterpret "unwarned" as a noun. But "young" is a noun in many other contexts. Clearly, from earlier comments, I wasn't the only one to interpret it as a noun.

Comment: Also, if "young" is intended to modify "brand" and not "family," it's especially ambiguous.

Comment: "**young**" does indeed modify "**brand**" but as an indirect object since the dirrect object is actually "**the messenger**"

Comment: You're speaking very authoritatively about something that is grammatically ambiguous. Did you write the article? Why would I not assume that the relevant noun "young" is modifying here is family members, since the whole article talks about people younger than 13 being able to use the Facebook brand?

Comment: It wasn't I who wrote this article but it is I who is trying to explain the meaning of it. What have the young to do with Facebook?

Comment: @ joiedevivre: Tᴚoɯɐuo suggested 'the young' as a collective noun and 'family' as an adjective. To me that's a very convincing explanation. What do you think?

Comment: @whitecap That's how I read it and what my answer was based on! I think SovereignSun has a good point that "young" might more likely have been intended to be an adjective. It's completely unclear which is true, though. And if it's an adjective, there's no way to know for certain what it was intended to modify. The only thing I'm completely convinced of is that it was badly written! It is a quote, though, so maybe the speaker can be forgiven. The writer should have found out what the speaker meant and clearly paraphrased it, though.

Answer (score 4):

> *That's why Facebook is doing this, of course — it's a safe way to get*
>   *their brand into **the family young***.

"The family young" is a noun phrase with "young" as head and the nominal "family" as attributive modifier.

It's called a fused modifier-head construction where "young" is an adjective functioning simultaneously as modifier and head in the NP "the family young", where we understand "young" to mean "young people". Note that "young" retains its status as an adjective within the NP.

It's no different to the "rich" found in "The rich cannot enter the kingdom of heaven", and the "poor" in "How will the new system affect the very poor?" In these examples "rich" and "poor" are adjectives functioning as fused modifier-heads within the noun phrases "the rich" and "the very poor".

Comment: So what does it mean? A young family (a family of young people)?

Comment: @Probably  It's another (not very good) way of saying "the young people in the family".

Answer (score 0):

I got the e-mail from Richard Lachman and here is his answer:

[image]

Comment: I think you meant "their new project." I also question your full interpretation. Even if you read "young" as an adjective, you'd be more likely to apply it to the "family" than the "project" in this context.

Comment: @joiedevivre The family isn't young, since messenger application aren't something new, but Facebook's one is young and is just entering this family

Comment: @SovereignSun: I don't think you understood the context properly. Facebook has launched Messenger Kids, a messaging app for children under 13.

By attracting new users to Messenger Kids when they're young, Facebook has the potential to convert them into full users of Facebook as they come of age.


Unlike Facebook, Messenger Kids itself is fairly harmless. As a chat tool, there's less concern about bullying or filter bubbles or the spread of misinformation. 

"That's why Facebook is doing this, of course — it's a safe way to get their brand into the family young."

Comment: @whitecap I understand the sentence as it is written otherwise it is Facebook who wrote it incorrectly and should be pointed to the mistake. It isn't ambiguos and "**young**" isn't a noun here. And it isn't modifying "**family**" - impossible!

Comment: Why is it impossible for a family to be young? Please explain. I think you were right that this is intended to be an adjective. I missed that. But the article is about something with the Facebook brand being available to kids under 13, now, so I think you are wrong that it is not intended to modify family. And I wholeheartedly stand by my assertion that it is badly written.

Comment: @SovereignSun: When I read the article it was my understanding that 'young' has something to do with young kids(under 13) not the new Facebook app, 'Messenger Kids'. If it is not too much bother, you could read the article yourself. I am not good at English so there's a good chance I might have understood wrong.

Comment: @whitecap I've read the article, but it seems that this Richard Larchman is talking about the new product Messenger Kids more than about the age of children or children themselves. Either he does indeed mean "**young family members**" whereupon his quote is badly written, or he's talking about the family of kid messengers which is young. Or maybe something else. Once I reach work I'll contact Facebook or maybe this Richard and ask what he means.

Comment: I have sent Richard Lachman an email, I hope he answers.

Comment: i recieved the e-mail and posted his answer.

Comment: @SovereignSun: I am surprised that he actually replied to your email. I would say he is a decent guy. Thank you for going an extra mile for my question to clear the air. I feel bad that I posted up an ambiguously written sentence not knowing any better.

Comment: @whitecap No problem there friend.